# Electron: Is it Possible to Update Existing browserWindow Options - Avoid Needing To Create a New Window

Tags: javascript, electron

I'd like to add a feature to toggle `alwaysOnTop`, but it seems like the only way to do this is to destroy my existing window and create a new one. Is there any way to update the options of the existing window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `browserWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(boolean flag)`.

Refer to https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetalwaysontopflag-level-relativelevel.

Comment: Thanks very much!